# Why does my Canon dSLR only work in autofocus with liveview and not the viewfinder?

Tags: autofocus, troubleshooting, canon-6d

When I have my camera (a Canon 6D Mark II) in AF mode, I can't take pictures (nothing happens when I click the shutter button) while using the viewfinder. I can take pictures using the screen though just fine. This happened after I sent my camera to a workshop for fixing another issue. I have used the lens that I am trying to do this with before and at that time it worked just fine.

The camera is not in video mode.

Comment: What does "can't take pictures" actually mean? Shutter doesn't activate? Picture taken but is not as expected (out of focus, blank, ....)? Error reported by camera body?

Comment: Shutter doesn't activate, nothing happens when I click on the shutter button

Comment: To clarify, does the camera take pictures if you're in manual focus and using the viewfinder?  Did you change exposure modes? What lens are you using?  When you press the shutter button is the subject in focus?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the camera is not locked into video mode as in this picture.

[image]

Comment: Yes, made sure that it wasn't

Answer (score 0):

If this happens with only a single lens, then chances are it is caused by something wrong with the lens, e.g. a bad autofocus motor, ribbon cable, lens control board, or lens contacts.

But assuming this occurs with all lenses, it sounds like they disconnected the focus sensor and didn't reconnect it correctly.